# How to fix the error "Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types"?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

import SwiftUI

struct FRemoteImage: View {

```
@ObservedObject var imageLoader = ImageLoader()

var placeholder:Image

init(url: String, placeholder: Image = Image(systemName: "photo")) {
    self.placeholder = placeholder
    imageLoader.fetchImage(url: url)
}

var body: some View {
    if let image = self.imageLoader.downloadImage {
        return Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 55, height: 60, alignment: .center)
    }
    return placeholder
}
```

}

struct FRemoteImage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
FRemoteImage(url: "")
}
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`body` in a SwiftUI is a `ViewBuilder` (which is a type of `ResultBuilder`), which has some special properties. To take advantage of it, you'll want to remove your explicit `return` statements and let it return a view hierarchy implicitly instead:

```
var body: some View {
    if let image = self.imageLoader.downloadImage {
        Image(uiImage: image) //<-- This gets returned
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 55, height: 60, alignment: .center)
    } else {
        placeholder  //<-- or, this gets returned
    }
}
```